# Update midlet wirelessly

Tags: java-me, installation, wireless, midlet

I am currently developing a j2me application for the i290 and would like to be able to update to new midlet revisions in my application using code.  The problem I am having is that one method that I know of that can do this, platformRequest(), is locked by motorola and I am not interesting in paying to sign my code.

I need a way to update the midlet via a network connection in my code without using a locked API or having to pay to do this.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you attempting to install a fresh updated midlet or trying to update the classes? The latter is not possible

Comment: I am trying to reinstall the entire .jar file in order to update the application.

Answer (score 1):

When you say it is "locked by Motorola" what exactly do you mean?  `platformRequest()` is definitely the usual way of upgrading a midlet on a device; are you quite sure that it doesn't work?  What happens when you call it?

In my fairly extensive J2ME experience I have seen quite a few things being unexpectedly disabled to unsigned apps, but never `platformRequest()`.  Try checking the method's return value; if it returns `true` you need to close the app yourself before the `platformRequest()` will happen (assuming it doesn't throw a `SecurityException`, but again I have never heard of a handset which does this).

If that fails then I guess you need to get the user to visit the upgrade URL manually through the handset's browser.

Comment: The method isn't completely locked; it seems that executing .jar/.jad files is disabled.